# bq M10: bluetooth keyboard and mouse at the same time?

Tags: keyboard, ubuntu-touch, mouse, bluetooth, m10

According to the user manual:

> Remember you can only link to one device at a time via Bluetooth, whether a keyboard or mouse. The other device must be connected via USB. You can  also connect to a single Bluetooth device which contains both a mouse and keyboard.

This seems completely ridiculous, and is contrary to all the promotional images that show it with a Bluetooth keyboard and mouse. I would consider it seriously broken if this was true.

I currently only have a BT keyboard, and would still need to buy a mouse. Has anybody tried it with both keyboard and mouse connected through BT?

Comment: As a bit of a summary of the different replies, it would seem that the M10 is in principle capable of having several BT devices (including KB and mouse) connected at the same time, but bluetooth seems to be quite flaky. Several other questions on askubuntu also point to intermittent bluetooth problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've connected both a keyboard an mouse via bluetooth to my BQ Aqauris M10 at the same time. Both worked fine and I was brought into convergence mode. For the record it was an apple wireless keyboard and rapoo mouse.

Comment: Also, I've bought a usb adapter that allows me to plug a regular mouse into the tablet. This device, coupled with a usb hub, allows me to plug both mouse and keyboard into the device sending it into convergence mode. I intend to get some bluetooth devices soon.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, only one (either mouse or keyboard) will connect automatically. Both bluetooth devices will work simultaneously, I just have to connect one manually via the Bluetooth menu.

Answer (score 1):

I connected both a Microsoft sculpt designer mouse and a logitech K480, both are working simultaneously.

The problem was to connect both devices, I had to try several times : first connect the mouse, then the keyboard was not detected, so i removed the mouse, then the M10 detected the K480 but not the mouse ... after several attempts both devices were finally detected and connected